# Jesse's real bad luck!

Tags: character, analysis, breaking-bad

Why Jesse always coincidentally comes in contact with those people who are related to drug business or drug addicts. Even Jane who seemed like a real nice girl was a Heroin addict. If Jane would have been a clean girl, Jesse would have had some chance of reconstructing his life. Even they planned to

> run away to NewZealand and start a new life.

Is this his bad luck or a real example of what goes around comes around and life is seriously a b**** (pun intended)?

Comment: It's part of the story; it was written like this so we have something to watch!

Answer (score 1):

**Out of the universe:**

Scenario. Because Walter White could have moved to Canada but then we would have no Breaking Bad. Same goes here, if Jesse settles...Well there is no more Jesse to follow.

**In universe**

Jesse was always going in drug related places, due to his activity as a meth cook and dealer. Even if he meets a nice girl, it's safe to assume that he would get along with someone who comes from the same places than him, so either a dealer, a cook or an addict as Jane.

So in some way he meets those drug related people "coincidentally" but in fact it's the only kind of people he can meet with, possibly the only one he can get along with.

You can also see that Walter White always pushes him to not quit the drug business, which reduces consequently his chances of giving up and "living a normal life".

Comment: "Because Walter White could have moved to Canada but then we would have no Breaking Bad." I like the joke, but it doesn't really hold true. Walt wasn't trying to pay for his medication; he was trying to provide a stable income for his family in his absence after his death. Canada would not guarantee his survival (unless they have a program that supplies income to widow(er)s?)

Comment: @Flater Well, as I'm not a canadian I can't tell wether life insurance is well handled here or not.